# Xaml - How to get exact row from grid (and change background)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, grid, row

I have defined grid in xaml like this:

```
<Grid Name="grdMoney" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     ... Content, many Textboxes in each row
</Grid>
```

Now I just want to highlight some row by changing background in that row. But I can't find out how can I get exact row from grid in code. I think it's easy but I am googling for last 15minutes and can't find it. Maybe something with `grdMoney.Childer[number_of_row]`? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grid` is a `Panel`. Panels are responsible for layouting, nothing more.
If you want to update background - put content of every row to `Border`, and find appropriate `Border` like that (i wrote code here, and didn't test it, but should work):

```
int desiredRowId = 2;
foreach(var child in grdMoney.Children.OfType<Border>())
{
    if (Grid.GetRow(child) == desiredRowId)
    { 
        child.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've probably'll do this in xaml using **[DataTriger](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/how-to-use-data-trigger-in-wpf)**

In data triger you can check your condition and apply appropriate background